# Java show double numbers

Tags: java, android

Below is the Java code:

```
Double val;
val = Double.parseDouble("2.2250738585072014e-308");
System.out.println(val.toString());
```

On my PC,

it'll show: 2.2250738585072014E-308

But on my Android device,
it'll show:

2.225073858507201E-308

One number less than PC

I wonder to know what makes the difference between these two devices having the same function?

Thank you~

Comment: I am not sure, but I think that differs from an android version to another.

Comment: I call it **approximation**

Comment: So it cause by different Hardware or just different Software version?(Java...or something)

Comment: Possibly by the ALU (the Arithmetic-Logic Unit of the CPU) or the math co-processor, if any.